# What are some audio/video converters for Linux?

Tags: downloads, video-conversion

What are some audio/video converters for Linux?

Comment: "closed" :( Thanks a lot moderators. This question was very important to me. ... did you notice that it was viewed twenty thousand times?

Answer (score 23):

I'm focusing on video converters here, although `FFmpeg` or `mencoder` can encode audio as well.

### Graphical interface

#### [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

From its homepage:

*HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder.*

Easy to use GUI with presets for various hardware devices; can rip DVDs with ease.

#### [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)

From its homepage:

*Avidemux is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering, and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs. Tasks can be automated using projects, job queue and powerful scripting capabilities.*

Also rather easy to use. It is somewhat comparable to VirtualDub on Windows.

#### [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)

VLC provides and easily accessible converting function in Media->Convert/Save. An instruction is given [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/08/vlc-allows-you-to-convert-videos-quick.html).

### Command line interface

#### [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) (or its fork `avconv`) ###

From its homepage:

*FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video codec library.*

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v mjpeg -b 2000k -c:a libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -vf denoise3d,scale=640:360 output.avi
```

#### [Mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)

`mencoder` is part of the MPlayer project, so it shares the same syntax.

Example:

```
mencoder input.wmv -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=3000 -oac mp3lame -lameopts cbr:br=160 -vf denoise3d,scale=640:360 -o output.avi
```

#### Handbrake

Handbrake also has a command line interface.

### Codec restrictions due to software patents

Be aware that due to software patents, some programs in the standard Ubuntu repositories don't include certain codecs (H264 *encoding* is a prominent example).

**Workarounds for stripped down binaries:**

#### Enable the [Medibuntu](http://www.medibuntu.org/) repositories:

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

#### Use a prebuilt static binary

For example, you can download FFmpeg with all codecs supported here: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/

If you want to run that binary, don't forget to call it with the full path; otherwise, the FFmpeg of Ubuntu will be run.

#### Build the binaries for yourself...

...and include everything you want. This is, of course, the most tedious solution.

Comment: For ffmpeg, at least, there is a pretty comprehensive [compilation guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) on the ffmpeg wiki.

Answer (score 3):

[A best video/audio converter of choice is WINFF (GUI of ffmpeg is here )](http://best-video-converter-for-windows.blogspot.com/2013/07/videoaudio-converter-for-linux.html)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @NomanJaved At this moment, the software you have linked has just versions for Windows and Mac, no Linux version.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you mean by `Best`. There are a lot of them out there. `ffmpeg` (`avconv`) is my favourite one. It is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video codec library. You can find more information from http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html