# Any application with graphical user interface to convert video files from mp4 to avi?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-conversion

I'm using Ubuntu and I have some `mp4` video files and I want to convert them to `avi` video file and I'm looking for an application to do it. I want an application with graphical user interface.

Any suggestion?

I tried the command line `ffmpeg` but I get some [problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270464/i-get-an-error-when-trying-to-convert-video)

Comment: I've compiled a list recently: [Which is best audio video converter on Linux?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264215/which-is-best-audio-video-converter-on-linux/264275#264275).

Comment: possible duplicate of [best video converter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/best-video-converter)

Answer (score 3):

You could give HandBrake a try.
http://handbrake.fr/

[image: handbrake screenshot]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Like a short description on how to install it and how to use it.

Comment: HandBrake doesn't convert to AVI anymore: http://handbrake.fr/news.php?article=10

Answer (score 1):

I guess Arista is just fine for you, it has the ability to convert mp4 file into avi and has support for more filetypes also... Installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/arista-transcoder-097-released-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try WINFF GUI of ffmpeg.

`sudo apt-get install winff`

Answer (score 1):

For me *FF Multi Converter* is the best app.

This is the official repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ffmulticonverter/stable
```

After this you must update with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmulticonverter
```

After this if you have problems with converting just install libavcodec-extra-53

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command and skip the GUI:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name '*.mp4'`; do avconv -i "$i" -qscale 1 "${i/.mp4/.avi}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Parts of this answer comes from: [Software for converting mp4 files from 720p to 480p](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620680/software-for-converting-mp4-files-from-720p-to-480p/638695#638695)

---

[Mobile Media Converter by Miksoft](https://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php) can be an easier way to do [transcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Transcoding) tasks.

[image]

In the above screenshot we can see a queue of videos (one in this example) to be processed with the same customised properties which includes transcoding for one or more of the next:

### For Audio

1. Audio Bitrate
2. Audio Frequency
3. Audio Channels
4. Audio Codec

For Video

1. Video Bitrate
2. Video FPS
3. Video Size
4. Video Codec

Of course you will be in need to add (on your own) the proper codecs for which you wish transcoding your video files so that they will become available in the "Video Codec" Drop Down.

Please have a look at this answer in which I explain something related.

[How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532)

Good luck!